# Future tense or future perfect tense, which one should be used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses

by 2050, time travel .... possible.

a) will be

b) will have been

which answer is correct? is it wrong to use "will be" in that case?

Comment: Why would it be wrong? Can you compose a sentence in which “will have been” would be right?

Comment: "Will have been possible" assumes that at some future time it no longer is possible. You might find a contrived sentence where it would work. Otherwise a) is right. If your're a language learner, you'll probably find the [ELL](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=english+language+learners+stack+exchange) site more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Will have" is *future perfect tense* and refers to something in the future that has been *completed*, but you want to refer to something (time travel) that will be *ongoing* in the future, so you need *future progressive*.

Therefore, 'a' is correct, at least grammatically:

> By 2050 time travel will be possible.

You would use "will have been" if you were referring to something completed that allows for the future possibility, for example:

> By 2050 the time machine *will have been* invented.

or simply:

> By 2050 time travel *will have been made* possible.

Answer (score 0):

Best to start by identifying if the verb describes a state or an action.
If a state, then it is likely that you wish to show that the state will exist at this point, and continue to exist further into the future.

state verbs, eg believe / prefer / be

By 2050 people will believe that all diseases are curable.
NOT: will have believed

By 2050 most people will prefer a vegetarian diet
NOT: will have preferred

By 2050 time travel will be possible
NOT: will have been

If an action, then a phrase beginning 'by + time/day/date', is more likely to employ a future perfect to show its completion no later than the specified time.

action verbs: close / disappear

By 2050 some species will have disappeared
NOT: will disappear

By 5pm that shop will have closed
NOT: will close